# Map with HashMap inside sublist

Tags: java, hashmap, sublist

How I can get sublist from?

```
Map<String, HashMap<String, String>>
```

I have tried:

```
Collections.list(Collections.enumeration(myMap.values())).subList(from,too)
```

**UPD:** 
Method returns `List<HashMap<String, String>>` only. But I need `List<String, HashMap<String,String>>`

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work?

Comment: What exactly do you expect the result to be?  A `HashMap` doesn't have a defined order, so populating a list with the values in a map and selecting a sublist will give you back arbitrary results.

Comment: Method returns  List<HashMap<String, String>> only. But I need List<String, HashMap<String,String>>

Comment: Just to be clear, there's no such thing as `List<String, HashMap<String,String>>`. but `LinkedHashMap<String, HashMap<String,String>>` is a very different thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use Map.entrySet(), not Map.values().  It will provide a set of key-value pairs, which is what you want.

If you are expecting the entries to be in the order you inserted them with, use LinkedHashMap instead of HashMap.

Also, unimportantly, consider getting rid of the enumeration, and just use `new ArrayList(myMap.entrySet())`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are seeing NullPointerException, then
Check if your "myMap" has properly initialized and have at least not empty.

If you are seeing IndexOutOfRangeException, then
Two arguments "from" and "to" should be in the range of map size.
from >= 0
to <= map's max size